# how to ping a server using different ip addresses in php

Tags: php

I want to ping a server using different ip addresses.

below is the sample code:

```
<?php

$ip = '76.76.21.246';
$port = '9000';

$server = 'blogsearch.google.com';


$fp = fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "POST /ping/RPC2/ HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: {$server}\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 128);
}
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

I am getting "requested url could not be retrieved" error

Can anyone let me know what is wrong in my code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: use `curl` for cross domain data retreival

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, you will get the same error when going to that URL with a normal browser too. Is the server configuration correct?

Comment: Why are you sending a HTTP POST request to that host? If all you need is the ping output, doesn't the PHP exec function make more sense?

Comment: @diEcho I need to send request through different ip and curl do not allow us to do that

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg i had visited that path through browser and it is fine

Comment: @Oldskool  is it possible to send request using exec function?

Answer (score 0):

use curl and set the CURLOPT_INTERFACE option to the ip address you desire